# How to ignore key if it comes from script, but fire it if it comes from keyboard in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a script that would fire a key if it comes from user, but not from script in AutoHotKey.

How can achieve this:
if `a` is pressed - `ab` is typed. if `b` is pressed - `c` is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~a::b` as a sign of "send a through, then send b".

If you are to use that three line method - you would need to use `$` to avoid infinite `a::` firing:

```
 $a::   
 Send {a}{b}  
 Return
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
~a::b
b::c
```

You can also do

```
$a::
Send {a}{b}
Return
```

Both work, but first is cleaner.

Fixed a bug.

Comment: Your second example would produce `bbbbbbbbbbbbbb...`